# Best method for converting an array of JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array embedded in JSON, and i need to convert some elements over to another array in JSON.  Is there a better method than iterating over the first to construct the second?

```
products = [{"name":"thing1","quantity":"1","price":11.52},{"name":"thing2","quantity":"1","price":1.28}]

items = [ {"product": "thing1", "quan": "1" }, {"product": "thing2", "quan": "1"} ]
```

Basically, i need to convert products to items in the snippet above.  My current approach is a for loop over products and create items.   It feels clunky.

Thoughts?
Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use `items = product.map(...)` instead of the `for` loop.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` with destructuring assignments:

```js
const products = [{"name":"thing1","quantity":"1","price":11.52},{"name":"thing2","quantity":"1","price":1.28}]

console.log(products.map(({name:product, quantity:quan})=>({product, quan})))
```

Comment: This was fantastic, and allowed me to add extra fields and all sorts - really good technique, thank you!